# Why does tf.matmul() give seemingly inconsistent results?

Tags: tensorflow

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
num_elements = 10
output = [[0.76158798] * num_elements]
softmax_w = [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]] * num_elements
print(tf.matmul(output, softmax_w).eval())
```

gives

```
[[ 0.76158804  0.76158804  0.76158804  0.76158804  0.76158804  0.76158804 0.76158804]]
```

Changing num_elements to 50

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
num_elements = 50
output = [[0.76158798] * num_elements]
softmax_w = [[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]] * num_elements
print(tf.matmul(output, softmax_w).eval())
```

gives

```
[[ 3.80794024  3.80794024  3.80794024  3.80794024  3.80793881  3.80793881 3.80793881]]
```

Why are the elements in the result matrix not all the same for the second example?

I'm using tensor flow 0.11.0rc0

Answer (score 1):

Seems it  was caused by numerical errors. I got the same results with your code, but then I made `output` and `softmax_w` the float64 tensors and the problem has disappeared:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
num_elements = 50
output = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.76158798] * num_elements], dtype = tf.float64)
softmax_w = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]] * num_elements, dtype = tf.float64)
print(tf.matmul(output, softmax_w).eval())
```

Comment: If it is a numerical error, why does it only affect some of the result elements? They all result from the same mathematical computation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is caused by the fact that your row length (7) is not an integer multiple of the number of floats that fit in an SSE register. For your larger example, the first 4 elements of the output are computed using a vectorized code path, while the last 3 are computed in a scalar "cleanup" loop. The order of the floating point additions performed in the vectorized and scalar versions of the code may differ slightly, and since floating point addition is not associative, slight differences on the order of

```
num_elements * std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon() * std::abs(result)
```

occur.