# Tensorflow conv2d result discrepancy on cpu vs gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

We've been working on a problem here that has yielded some discrepancies between results based on what we've observed to be caused by a couple of factors which should theoretically have no impact.

In our problem, we're dealing with a data set that is varying in size.  During training, the input is fixed to a specific size by either padding or chopping.  However, in the interest of performance and speed, we were hoping to take advantage of the fact that we should be able to pre-calculate the results of feeding an input consisting of only padding through the layers of our convolutional neural net.  Thus for inputs significantly smaller than the fixed size set in training, we would determine the bare minimum amount of padding required to have the activations generated by the final conv layer match those of the same input if it were padded out to that large fixed size, in addition to as much of the pre-calculated all-pad activations that would need to be appended to the result.

The conv-net portion of our model that we were experimenting with this on consists of 9 layers, the first eight performing a conv2d followed by a maxpool, and the final one being a single conv2d.  The training for the model was performed on gpu's, however, for testing we only have the cpu available.  Testing on a large set of data using the variable padding approach yielded for the most part identical results to what we would expect to see compared to the fixed size input.  However, there were a few cases where we observed discrepancies between the values obtained using the two approaches, sometimes on the order of e-4.

This issue looked to manifest itself only in input which were on the smaller end of the scale.  Digging down into these cases revealed that the activations from each layer in the model were always identical, and it wasn't until you reach the final convolution layer where the discrepancies appeared.  Surprisingly though, we discovered that adding enough padding (still far below the fixed size) could affect the value of the first few activations at the final layer, even though those cells don't depend on that extra padding at all.

We were able to replicate the problem using canned data, and even demonstrate it on a single conv2d operation.  In the code below, A simple conv2d with a single length:5 stride:1 filter is applied to a tensor of length 7 to produce 3 activations.  However, when you append 1 or 2 extra values on to the input, the values of the 2nd and 3rd activations change even though they have no dependence on these new input values at all.  Replicating the results by hand using tf.mul and reduce_sum ops, produces the same results as the input with the extra values, indicating that it's the correct result.  This is only observed when the ops are executed on the cpu, however, assigning them to the gpu instead always produces the same values regardless of whether the input is of length 7, 8, or 9.  Is this expected when performing conv on the cpu?  Is there a way to explain the variance in the conv output, eg. does it happen due to the algorithm used for small inputs?  All of the above refers to conv2d with VALID padding used.

example:

```
# Consider a length-T tensor x0 where T>=5.  Create another tensor
# x1 by adding an element onto the end of x0.  If you convolve both
# x0 and x1 with a length-5 filter with VALID padding, you'd expect
# the first (T-4) elements of the resulting tensors to have the
# exact same value because the calculation is being done on the
# same set of numbers.  It turns out you can get discrepancies
# though on the order of e^-5 if the convolution is done on the CPU.

#device = '/gpu:0'
device = '/cpu:0'

T = 7  # >=5

def expand_4d(f, n):
    f = tf.expand_dims(f, n[0])
    f = tf.expand_dims(f, n[1])
    f = tf.expand_dims(f, n[2])
    return f

# Convolution Filter and Bias
cnv = tf.cast([-0.7313, -1.1043, 1.8492, 1.3007, -0.1033], tf.float32)
cnv = expand_4d(cnv, [0, -1, -1])
bias = tf.constant([0.0401], tf.float32)

# Input
x0 = 10.0 * tf.cast(tf.range(T), tf.float32)
x1 = 10.0 * tf.cast(tf.range(T+1), tf.float32)
x2 = 10.0 * tf.cast(tf.range(T+2), tf.float32)
x0 = expand_4d(x0, [0, 0, -1])
x1 = expand_4d(x1, [0, 0, -1])
x2 = expand_4d(x2, [0, 0, -1])

# Run Convolution
def my_conv(x):
    with tf.device(device):
        return tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(x, cnv, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='VALID'), bias)

y0 = my_conv(x0)
y1 = my_conv(x1)
y2 = my_conv(x2)
n = T - 4   # length of y0

sess = tf.Session()
y0_, y1_, y2_ = sess.run([y0, y1, y2])
print('T =', T)
print('device =', device)
print('y0 = convolution with length-T tensor x0')
print(y0_)
print('y1 = convolution with length-(T+1) tensor x1')
print(y1_)
print('y2 = convolution with length-(T+2) tensor x2')
print(y2_)
# Compare the first n elements of each tensor (should all be equal)
print('y0 - y1[0:%s]' % n)
print(y0_[0][0] - y1_[0][0][0:n])
print('y1[0:%s] - y2[0:%s]' % (n, n))
print(y1_[0][0][0:n] - y2_[0][0][0:n])
```

sample output:

```
T = 7
device = /cpu:0
y0 = convolution with length-T tensor x0
[[[[ 60.87010574]
   [ 72.98010254]
   [ 85.09010315]]]]
y1 = convolution with length-(T+1) tensor x1
[[[[ 60.87010574]
   [ 72.98009491]
   [ 85.09008789]
   [ 97.20009613]]]]
y2 = convolution with length-(T+2) tensor x2
[[[[  60.87010574]
   [  72.98009491]
   [  85.09008789]
   [  97.20009613]
   [ 109.31010437]]]]
y0 - y1[0:3]
[[  0.00000000e+00]
 [  7.62939453e-06]
 [  1.52587891e-05]]
y1[0:3] - y2[0:3]
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
```

Comment: generic comment -- you can have numeric difference due to different input shape. Here are two recent example that come to mind -- different algorithm is [used](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2234) for CPU tanh when input is size is 4 or less , a new codepath for cudnn was recently added -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/0318cf082ee88ff0e226a5bf7da0487f44d82182

Comment: There is also an interesting [SSE alignment issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40340570/why-does-tf-matmul-give-seemingly-inconsistent-results) that may be related.